# CMake: How to copy different files to build directory according to configuration and architecture

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, post-build-event, post-build

I'm generating my `vcxproj` and `sln` files for `MSVC` with [CMake](https://cmake.org/). I want to copy some `dlls` in build directory as `POST_BUILD` event which are different according whether I'm building `Debug` or `Release` configuration and whether it is `x86` or `x64` architecture. I'm using `add_custom_command` the following way

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
    ${FILES_TO_COPY} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
```

I want to set `FILES_TO_COPY` to different values according to architecture and configuration or to use different `add_custom_command` according the same conditions. But CMake MSVC is multi config generator and `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is empty under it and I cannot simply write something like:

```
if (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 4)
  if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")

    set (FILES_TO_COPY
      "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/DLLs/bdb/Debug/i386/libdb52d.dll")

  elseif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")

    set (FILES_TO_COPY
      "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/DLLs/bdb/Release/i386/libdb52.dll")

  else ()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Invalid configuration name ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}.")
  endif ()
elseif (CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
  if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")

    set (FILES_TO_COPY
      "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/DLLs/bdb/Debug/x64/libdb52d.dll")

  elseif (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Release")

    set (FILES_TO_COPY
      "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/DLLs/bdb/Release/x64/libdb52.dll")

  else ()
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Invalid configuration name ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}.")
  endif ()
else ()
  message (FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported architecture with ${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}
    bytes pointer size.")
endif ()
```

How to do this properly?

Comment: if you studied the output of the compiler when invoked with --help, or --version would that help?

Comment: @Richard Hodges I don't  know how to study the output of the compiler from **CMake** and how to invoke it with `--help` or `--version` from **CMake**.

Comment: execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} --version/help? OUTPUT_VARIABLE compiler_output) or similar

Comment: @Richard Hodges The output contains architecture type which I also can determine with `CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P ` but it cannot contain `Debug` or `Release` which are real problem.

Comment: Ah I see. The answer below using generator expressions solves it though, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
set(arch "i386")
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    set(arch "x64")
endif()

set(FILES_TO_COPY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Externals/DLLs/bdb/$<CONFIG>/${arch}/libdb52$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>.dll")
```

Comment: +1 10x This works for this case but I can't accept this answer because the path to files is not required to contain `Debug`, `Release`, `i386` or `x64`. For some of the other files which I have to add the pattern in the path can be different if any.

Comment: @bobeff: For general cases you may use `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:path-debug>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:path-release>` pattern. See documentation for generator expressions: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I think that this completes the answer and I'm accepting it.